# When debugging Cordova app in visual studio styles window is empty

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, taco

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and TACO Tools and when trying to debug Corodva app in Ripple (or even on VS Android Emulator) I often get empty styles window (though DOM exlorer seems to work ok). Sometimes it happens that step by step debugging works, but DOM Explorer doesn't appear.

Any ideas?

Below is version of my VS

[image]

[image: cordova app debugger blank styles field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a change to the remote debug protocol that broke Visual Studio's DOM explorer implementation. We'll have a fix for this in update 1.

I'm sorry for any inconvenience this has caused you. (Disclosure: I work for Microsoft)

Comment: thank you for propmt response. I wonder when is update 1 due?

Comment: Soon :) I don't think we've announced a release date or I'd be more specific.

Comment: Update 1 is available for download now at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by downgrading to Chrome 43.  (Note: I would not use the browser anymore for internet use).

You can install it from here:
https://dl.google.com/chrome/win/4ED6DD719811795B/43.0.2357.134_chrome_installer.exe

Before you install it you need to make the following registry changes to keep it from updating (put in a .reg file and import it):

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update]
"Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Google\Update]
"Update{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}"=dword:00000000